# CSS Layout: no line break between divs, even if browser window is too small

Tags: css, layout, line-breaks

I know this isn't exactly a new topic but all my researches were without a result.

What I try to accomplish:

1. Two divs inside one div, next to each other. (easy: float, inline-block)
2. If the browser window is to small the divs should stay next to each other.

What happens right now:
If the browser window is not wide enough, the second div slips under the first one.

Example: http://pastebin.com/e9cuWjwT

How can I solve that?

Comment: Are your two divs fixed/known width? What about their height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="selection">Menu 1</div>
    <div class="selection">Menu 2</div>
    <div class="selection">Menu 3</div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* set to what you need */
}
div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The table cells will always stay in a single row and their widths will adjust as the width of the parent block (with `display: table`) adjusts to the width of the browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you add width to the container surrounding your divs, they will stay next to each other even if the screen real estate gets smaller.  Because you've told the browser how big you want container to be, resizing the screen won't affect their placement.

Here's is a fiddle with very simplified code to show a scenario that works:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lera/CmJhw/1/

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
   width:1024px;
}
div {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>First Div</div>
    <div>Second Div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought of that too but the problem is I don't know the width of the divs. The first one could get a fixed size but the other one isn't predictable.

Comment: The divs don't need a size, just a container around them.  You can give the container a giant size if you want, just so long as it has a size. Give it 5000px if you want.  That's the wrapper, not the two side-by-side divs.